# determining the spacing in the data based on the density

Tags: matlab

I am right now using the following code to create spacing in the data:

`spX = linspace(min(data.X),max(data.X),500);
 spY = linspace(min(data.Y),max(data.Y),500);`

This creates uniform spacing, Is there away to determing spX and spY based on the data density?

Comment: _determing spX and spY based on the data density_ how exactly? What do you want to achieve? Please give an example with input and output

Comment: you mean by `spx=min(data.X):mean(diff(data.X)):max(data.X)` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [quantile](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/quantile.html) :

```
spX = quantile(data.X, 500);
spY = quantile(data.Y, 500);
```